# How do you code the ideal weight range for a man and a woman

Tags: java, height

I already coded the ideal weight for a man and a woman when you input your height.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class height
{
public static void main (String []args)
{
    int Feet, Inches, Totalinches, Maleweight, Femaleweight;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("Please enter your height in feet and inches...");

    System.out.println ("Feet: ");
    Feet = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println ("Inches: ");
    Inches = scan.nextInt();

    Totalinches = Feet*12 + Inches; 
    Maleweight = 106 + (Totalinches - 60)*6;
    Femaleweight = 100 + (Totalinches - 60)*5;

    System.out.println ("The ideal weight for a " + Feet + " foot " + Inches +  " male is " + Maleweight + " pounds.");

    System.out.println ("A weight in the range  to  is okay.");

    System.out.println ("The ideal weight for a " + Feet + " foot " + Inches + " female is " + Femaleweight + " pounds.");

    System.out.println ("A weight in the range  and  is okay.");
}
```

}

Where it says **"A weight in the range..."** I need to input code that includes a formula that calculates the ideal weight range. A chart that says all the ideal weight ranges that correspond with the height is found here:

[BMISurgery](http://bmisurgery.org/index.php?ID=findyouridealweight)

I appreciate every little help that is given, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the values in that table without recurring to a formula to calculate them, you can use some maps to store them

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> minimumMaleWeight = new HashMap<>();
    minimumMaleWeight.put(54, 63);
    minimumMaleWeight.put(55, 68);
    minimumMaleWeight.put(56, 74);
    minimumMaleWeight.put(57, 79);      

    Map<Integer, Integer> maximumMaleWeight = new HashMap<>();
    maximumMaleWeight.put(54, 77);
    maximumMaleWeight.put(55, 84);
    maximumMaleWeight.put(56, 90);
    maximumMaleWeight.put(57, 97);

    System.out.println(minimumMaleWeight.get(Totalinches));
    System.out.println(maximumMaleWeight.get(Totalinches));
```

if you want to use a formula to calculate them instead, looks like rounding up 5.4*Totalinches-228.7 might work ([here is where I got the numbers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20fit%20%7B%7B54,63%7D,%7B55,68%7D,%7B56,74%7D,%7B57,79%7D%7D), you can do the same for the maximum weight)

Comment: Thank you very much deathyr for helping me find the minimum number for the weight range. I am sorry if this is a lot of trouble, but would you please explain how to get the formula for the maximum weight? I am not sure how you got the numbers such as "(54, 63), (55, 68)" and how to linear fit it to find the maximum weight. I have only started learning java for a few weeks. Thank you again for your hard effort.

Comment: Wolframalpha is a website that can run all kind of math for you, just give it the numbers and it will do linear fit for you. I got the numbers from the table, For example for male
4' 6" (=54'') ----> 63 - 77 lbs. 
4' 7"  (=55'') --------> 68 - 84 lbs. 
4' 8" (=56'')----------->74 - 90 lbs.
Here is the linear fit for maximum weight: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear+fit+%7B%7B54,77%7D,%7B55,84%7D,%7B56,90%7D,%7B57,97%7D%7D